# How to use scope in loopback filter in json format

Tags: node.js, angular, loopback4

I am trying to make call from my angular service to loopback api. I have a parcelStatuses collection that contains a `parcelId` so i am able to include parcel collection too but I also need to check against a particular `vendorId` and that `vendorId` exists in `parcel` collection. I am trying to make use of scope to check against particular vendorId but i think i am not writing correct json syntax/call. Here is my function inside service

```js
private getParcelsByFilter(
  limit: number,
  skip: number,
  vendorId: string,
  filter: string
) {
  const checkFilter = {
  "where": {
    "and": [{"statusRepositoryId": filter}]
  },
  "include": [
      {
        "parcel": [
          {
            "scope": {"vendorId": vendorId}
          },
          "parcelStatuses", 
          {"customerData":"customer"}
        ]
      }
    ],
    "limit": limit,
    "skip": skip,
  }

  return this._http.get<IParcel[]>(
    `${environment.url}/ParcelStatuses?filter=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(checkFilter))}`
  );
}
```

Here is my demo view of parcelStatus collection object

```
[{
 "id":"lbh24214",
 "statusRepositoryId":"3214fsad",
 "parcelId":"LH21421"
}]
```

Demo json of parcel

```
[{
 "id":"LHE21421",
 "customerDataId":"214fdsas",
 "customerId":"412dsf",
 "vendorId":"123421"
}]
```

Please help me with writing correct call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting aside, there's several issues with the query:

### Unnecessary `and`

This line:

```js
where: {
  and: [{statusRepositoryId: filter}]
}
```

Can be simplified to:

```js
where: {
  statusRepositoryId: filter
}
```

As there is only 1 `where` condition, `and` becomes redundant.

### Misuse of `include` and `scope`

`include` is used to include relations while `scope` applies filters to those relations. They can work in tandem to create a comprehensive query:

```js
include: [
  {
    relation: "parcels",
    scope: {
      where: {vendorId: vendorId},
    }
  }
],
```

This will include the `parcels` relation as part of the response, while filtering the `parcels` relation with a `where` filter.

---

That means the final code should look similar to the following:

```js
private getParcelsByFilter(
  limit: number,
  skip: number,
  vendorId: string,
  filter: string
) {
  const checkFilter = {
  where: {statusRepositoryId: filter},
  include: [
      {
        relation: "parcels",
        scope: {
          where: {vendorId: vendorId},
        }
      }
    ],
    limit: limit,
    skip: skip,
  }

  return this._http.get<IParcel[]>(
    `${environment.url}/ParcelStatuses?filter=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(checkFilter))}`
  );
}
```

---

### Further reading

Please review these resources to get a better understanding on how to use filters.

- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Include-filter.html

Comment: Thank you for your answere Rifa. I got it fixed from backend side by running script on data and added the required property inside the parcelStatus collection. So then `and` was necessary `"where":{"and":[{statusRepositoryId:"3214fsad"},{"vendorId":"123421"}]..}`. Also i needed to inlude parcelStatus complete array inside each parcel array again because of some of those values will be used in table. However your solution is right too, thanks